# How to load data on swipe in iDangerous Swiper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using iDangerous Swiper for mobile slider. everything is fine, But I don't know how to load data in slider when user swipe to particular slider div. In short I want to load data on swipe.

Please check the snippet.

Another problem is I also want to load data On click of link, in this case "**Slide to 3**". I want to retrieve the ID of post using `data-post` and then I want to load some Ajax data in the current slider div.

So basically what I need i on click of link slide to particular slider and then load data using link attributions. After that if user swipe to another slide then I want to load other data in that slide.

I know its confusing and really sorry for English. :(

Thank you

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        slideToClickedSlide:true,
        loop: true,
        preloadImages: false,
        lazyLoading: true
    });
    
    $('#btn').click(function(){
    var slider = $(this).data("slider");
swiper.slideTo(slider, 1000, false);
})
```

```css
html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div>
    <a href="#" id="btn" data-slider="3" data-post="234"> Slide to 3</a>
    </div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    </div>
```